# The understanding the logic of Body is might complete normally error

Tags: flutter, dart

as a beginner it is really hard to understand to fix this error.

from another page I am sending parameters to Widget. Here is the widget:

```
Widget customListTile3(List<Datum> articles, int index, BuildContext context) {
  final urlImages = [
    articles[0].imageUrl!,
    articles[1].imageUrl!,
    articles[2].imageUrl!,
    articles[3].imageUrl!,
  ];

  String? time = DateFormat(
    'd MMMM yy',
  ).format(
    DateTime.parse(
      '${articles[index].date!}'.toString(),
    ),
  );
  Container(
    // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        boxShadow: const [
          BoxShadow(color: Colors.white, blurRadius: 1, offset: Offset(0, 0)),
        ]),
  );
  Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: CarouselSlider.builder(
          options: CarouselOptions(
            viewportFraction: 1,
          ),
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (context, idx, realIndex) {
            return buildImage(articles, urlImages[idx], idx, context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );

  return NewsLoading(text: 'wait');
}
```

this code snippets works but run only NewsLoading widget (circle progress bar) but index or article variables bot of them not nulls.

Why not triggering anything except NewsLoading? When I remove return statement I am getting this time Body is complete normally error.

I am trying to understand the logic here.

BTW, I tried to add if statement if index or article null then do something different, but it says index and article cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

You instantiated a `Container` and a `Column` but you did not return them.

Where did you mean to place them? Did you mean to return a container with all three alements in them?

I'm afraid I don't know what you where trying to do, but you need to actually *return* your full widget. right now you are only returning this specific widget: `return NewsLoading(text: 'wait');` and that is why you only see this widget and not the others you have created, but not returned.